# Problem using sed back reference

Tags: sed

I am trying to remove some junk and substitute words with the key digits, starting with strings like:

```
>ref|NC_035781.1|  
>ref|NC_035782.1|   
>ref|NC_035783.1|   
>ref|NC_035784.1|
```

and wanting to end with:

```
>NC_035781.1  
>NC_035782.1  
>NC_035783.1  
>NC_035784.1
```

I tried

```
sed 's/\>ref\|NC_03578\([0-9]\)\.1\|/>NC_03578\1\.1/g' chr.test | grep '>NC_'
```

to test it and got back many more results than expected looking like:

```
>NC_03578.1>>NC_03578.1r>NC_03578.1e>NC_03578.1f>NC_03578.1|>NC_035780.1|>NC_03578.1 >NC_03578.1C>NC_03578.1r>NC_03578.1a>NC_03578.1s>NC_03578.1s>NC_03578.1o>NC_03578.1s>NC_03578.1t>NC_03578.1r>NC_03578.1e>NC_03578.1a>NC_03578.1   
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sed 's/ref\||//g' file`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that you have escaped `>` and `|` and I suspect you are using `GNU sed`. In which case, `\>` acts as end of word boundary and `\|` will act as alternation operator.

```
$ sed 's/>ref|\(NC_03578[0-9]\.1\)|.*/>\1/' chr.test
>NC_035781.1
>NC_035782.1
>NC_035783.1
>NC_035784.1
```

The modified command is shown above. Also, there seems to be some spaces at end of line, so I've added `.*` to remove them. Use `sed -n '/NC_/ s/>ref|\(NC_03578[0-9]\.1\)|.*/>\1/p'` to include the `grep` operation within `sed` itself

You can also use `awk`

```
$ awk -F'|' '/NC_/{print ">" $2}' chr.test
>NC_035781.1
>NC_035782.1
>NC_035783.1
>NC_035784.1
```

- `-F'|'` to define `|` as field separator. `|` is a regexp operator, but when `FS` (the field separator special awk variable set by `-F`) is a single character, it is not treated as a regexp. `-F'[|]'` or `-F'\\|'` would also work but would be less efficient.
- `/NC_/` if input line contains `NC_`

  - `print ">" $2` print `>` character and the second field